# JOOQ update query always returning 1

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, jooq

I have a MySQL update query like so:

```sql
UPDATE personInfo SET Email='blah@blah.com', FirstName='Bob', LastName='Smith', Lang='EN' WHERE RowID=12345 and PoolRowID=1001;
```

RowID is a unique key and we add the PoolRowID just for safety. I call this through JOOQ like so:

```java
// results in a JOOQ stmt equivalent to the SQL stmt above
UpdateConditionStep<ContactRecord> updateQuery = createUpdatePersonInfoTableQuery(id, personInfo, create);
int ret = updateQuery.execute();
```

But ret is always 1 whether the data is actually changed or not. In other words, even if the UPDATE statement is setting all the values to their existing values, ret is still 1. I have dumped the resulting JOOQ SQL out and executed it from the MySQL command line and I get Rows Changed = 0.

So JOOQ seems to be returning the number of rows matched, rather than the number of rows affected. But both the JOOQ docs and the MySQL docs indicate that UPDATE returns the number of rows affected.

Am I doing something wrong with my query?

Comment: jOOQ doesn't do any magic. This value is returned straight from the JDBC driver.

Comment: If the row exists, and you update it, even if you update it with the same values, that will still count as an update (maybe not in all databases). It might also be a semantic thing, your MySQL command line says _rows **changed**_, while the API doc of `executeUpdate` only says _"the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements"_